# subscriptionFilter not working in serverless framework

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

```
plugins:
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-plugin-log-retention
  - serverless-esbuild # used for compiling/packaging the Typescript code
  - serverless-offline # used for local execution
  - serverless-plugin-subscription-filter


functions:
  notifier:
    handler: app/functions/notifier/notifier.handler
    events:
      - subscriptionFilter:
          stage: ${self:provider.region}
          logGroupName: /aws/lambda/thincc-parser-${self:provider.region}-lambdaParser
          filterPattern: '{ $.message like /ERROR/ }`
```

this is my code from serverless.yml I get this error when i deploy it

`Warning: Invalid configuration encountered at 'functions.notifier.events.0': unsupported function event`

Checked indentation issues, official document... nothing works

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-subscription-filter